# removing wrong code and associated records in R data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table in R, say dt which looks like:

```
> dt <- data.table(adr = c("A", "A", "A","A","A","A","A","B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E"),
                  code=c("0001","0001","0001","0001","0001","0001","0001","0001","0001", "0002", "0002", "0002", "0003", "0003", "0003"),
                  num = c(1,67,875,467,986,34,987,876,785, 67,9078,45,907,451,987))
> dt
    adr code  num
 1:   A 0001    1
 2:   A 0001   67
 3:   A 0001  875
 4:   A 0001  467
 5:   A 0001  986
 6:   A 0001   34
 7:   A 0001  987
 8:   B 0001  876
 9:   B 0001  785
10:   C 0002   67
11:   C 0002 9078
12:   C 0002   45
13:   D 0003  907
14:   E 0003  451
15:   E 0003  987
```

for a single value of `code` there can be a single value of `adr`. So for example for `code = 0001`, here we have two adr `A` and `B`. which is wrong. That `adr` and its associated records are correct which have majority of occurance for that particular code(more than 50%).

So for code 0001 , adr A is 7 times and adr B is 2 times, hence adr B and its associate records are wrong. I want to find this and want to remove the wrong records for each of the code.

The output must look like:

```
> dt
        adr code  num
     1:   A 0001    1
     2:   A 0001   67
     3:   A 0001  875
     4:   A 0001  467
     5:   A 0001  986
     6:   A 0001   34
     7:   A 0001  987
     8:   C 0002   67
     9:   C 0002 9078
    10:   C 0002   45
    11:   E 0003  451
    12:   E 0003  987
```

How can I do this in R  with data.table

Comment: `dt = dt[dt$adr != "B",]` ?

Comment: What happens if there are ties for most occurrence adr or the majority occurrence doesn't exceed 50%?

Comment: in case of tie, first one is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your `dt` a `data.frame()` instead of a `data.table()` so I wouldn't have to load another package, but You can accomplish this as follows:

```
require(dplyr)

dt <- dt %>% group_by(code, adr) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% group_by(code) %>% filter(count == max(count)) %>% select(-count)
```

Comment: `data.table` version: `dt2 <- dt[, N := .N, by = .(code, adr)][, .SD[N > 0.5 * .N], by = code][, N := NULL]`

Comment: It is giving not giving the result , the wrong records are still there:

Comment: @Jack If what you wanted was to have the mode (the most common occurrence), this would do the trick: `dt[, { uadr = unique(adr); .SD[which(adr == uadr[which.max(tabulate(match(adr, uadr)))]), ] }, by=c('code')]`. It might be helpful if there are more than 2 alternative addresses.